# How to use 'interactive' arguments when calling the command from code

Tags: commands

I have a command called `test` which simply takes an input from the user and echoes it back:

```
(defun test (input)
  (interactive "MInput: ")
  (message "%s" input))
```

I want to write another function which would call it. The following fails:

```
(defun test-forward ()
  (interactive)
  (test))
```

with this error

```
test-forward: Wrong number of arguments: (lambda (input) (interactive "MInput: ") (message "%s" input)), 0
```

This makes sense, since `test` takes one input. Making `test`'s `input` `&optional` simply makes `test-forward` return `nil` without doing anything. What is the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply:

```
(call-interactively 'test)
```